# Loops in R-studio

Tags: r, loops

```
rnorm <- set.seed(999)

A <- “NULL”
```

Mean is 100 and sd=5

I wanted to know how to perform a loop in R  that terminated the loop if the random value is less than 80, otherwise, appends random value to the vector names A. When loop has ended display the vector

Comment: That's not how `rnorm(...)` or `set.seed` work, and those "fancy quotes" don't work correctly in R. You mentioned a loop but have nothing in your code, and you mention a mean and sd with no apparent use for them. What are you doing?

Comment: FYI, with that random seed, it'll take over 77000 iterations in a loop to get a random number (mean 100 sd 5) below 80: `set.seed(999); r <- rnorm(78000, 100, 5); which(r < 80);`. (This makes sense, since 80 has a z-score of -4.)